# Angular how to concatenate the results of many observable using concatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

I wrote four api and i have decided to concatenate all their results using rxjs operator concatMap

All i was doing is to call them one by one , for each observable i push all the results and move to the next. Unfortunately i go so many syntax errors like Argument of type '(resTasks: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput' because i was doing some treatement.

```js
  listProjectWithConcatMap(projectId:number) :any {
    let issuesList:any = [];
    const headers = { 'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()};
      this.listProjectTasks(projectId).pipe(
        concatMap((resTasks) => {
         for(var item of resTasks.body) {
          issuesList.add(item);
         }
         this.listProjectSprints(projectId);
        })
        concatMap((resSprints) => {
          for(var item of resSprints.body) {
           issuesList.add(item);
          }
          this.listProjectSprints(projectId);
         }
        )
        concatMap((resEpics) => {
          for(var item of resEpics.body) {
           issuesList.add(item);
          }
          this.listProjectEpics(projectId);
         }
        )
        concatMap((resStories) => {
          for(var item of resStories.body) {
           issuesList.add(item);
          }
          this.listProjectStories(projectId);
         }
        )
      )
    return issuesList;
  }
```

I do not know how to fix the syntax problems but i am sure that using concatMap operator is a right choice for this situation.

example of listProjectTasks

```js
 listProjectTasks(projectId:number) :Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()};
    return this.http.get<any>(SERVER_BASE_URL+this.PREFIX+'/get/'+projectId+'/tasks/list', { headers });
  }
```

example of listProjectEpics

```js
  listProjectEpics(projectId:number) :Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()};
    return this.http.get<any>(SERVER_BASE_URL+this.PREFIX+'/get/'+projectId+'/epics/list', { headers });
  }
```

Comment: I can already see that your function will always return an empty `issuesList` since you're adding item to the list inside the observable but returning it outside. Also, can you explain why you believe that `concatMap` is the right operator for this? From the look of it the result of 1 observable doesn't rely on the previous one at all so order shouldn't matter here?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your comment.its' right here that the order does not matter , but i wanted it to happen by this order. i understand the problem but is there anyway return an obsevable that contains all the results of the last observables? i tried to subscribe in the component and i got an error that says that subscribe is not a property. so what i am trying to do is returning an observable that contains the list of concatenation just like i did with issuesList to subscribe to it later in the component later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to by pass the error and return the the pipe with all the concatenated observables then here's the syntax:

```
  listProjectWithConcatMap(projectId: number): Observable<any> {
    const issuesList: any[] = [];
    return this.listProjectTasks(projectId).pipe(
      concatMap((resTasks) => {
        for (var item of resTasks.body) {
          issuesList.push(item);
        }
        return this.listProjectSprints(projectId);
      }),
      concatMap((resSprints) => {
        for (var item of resSprints.body) {
          issuesList.push(item);
        }
        return this.listProjectSprints(projectId);
      }),
      concatMap((resEpics) => {
        for (var item of resEpics.body) {
          issuesList.push(item);
        }
        return this.listProjectEpics(projectId);
      }),
      concatMap((resStories) => {
        for (var item of resStories.body) {
          issuesList.push(item);
        }
        return this.listProjectStories(projectId);
      }),
      map(() => issuesList)
    );
  }
}
```

Some mistakes that you made that causes the syntax errors:

- There's no such thing as `add` for array in Javascript, so we use push here instead
- `concatMap` require that you return an observable at the end of the callback, which you did not, so we add `return ...` for all of them
- Returning the array outside the `pipe` will just make the function return an empty array. What you want here is to return it as part of the pipe so that the function will return an observable of `issueslList`, therefor we use the `map` operator at the end.

This will work (I hope). But yeah it does not look great, there's no safe typing, error handling and the codes in general look kinda sus.

Comment: thanks for your help, absolutely your answer is what i am looking for. It's an opprtunity to learn more about rxJs

Answer (score 0):

Not RxJS expert, but you can achieve with:

```js
import {
  concatMap,
  of,
  tap,
  map
} from 'rxjs';

const ob1 = this.listProjectTasks(projectId).pipe(
  tap((resTasks) => {
    for (var item of resTasks.body) {
      issuesList.push(item);
    }
  })
);

const ob2 = this.listProjectSprints(projectId).pipe(
  tap((resSprints) => {
    for (var item of resSprints.body) {
      issuesList.push(item);
    }
  })
);

const ob3 = this.listProjectEpics(projectId).pipe(
  tap((resEpics) => {
    for (var item of resEpics.body) {
      issuesList.push(item);
    }
  })
);

const ob4 = this.listProjectStories(projectId).pipe(
  tap((resStories) => {
    for (var item of resStories.body) {
      issuesList.push(item);
    }
  })
);

return of(ob1).pipe(
  concatMap((ob) => ob2),
  concatMap((ob) => ob3),
  concatMap((ob) => ob4),
  map((x) => issuesList)
);
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvhv71?file=src/app/dummy.service.ts)

The reason why to use `.tap()` as the observable value doesn't need to transform the observable value. It is just doing the tasks to add values into `issueList` array. Lastly, transform the observable to return `issueList`.

*Feel welcome to provide suggestions and improve the answer (if there is better/simpler way). Thanks.*